# jQuery width() doesn't work on div

Tags: jquery, width

currently I'm trying to make this page responsive:
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/orchid/pleione/2013-03-25_Pleione_Ueli_Wackernagel_Pearl.php
A lot is working already but one problem is left: The jQuery function width() doesn't change the divs width. With height it's working fine. Also for the width of the video element. You can see it when you reduce the browsers width. (I've given a red border to the div.)
My code (extract):

```
    $('img').each(function (idx) {
        s = $(this).attr("src");
        if (s.indexOf("buttonleft.png") < 0 &&
        s.indexOf("buttonright.png") < 0 &&
        s.indexOf("buttonup.png") < 0) {
            var wimage = $(this).width();
            if (!owimage[s] || wimage > owimage[s]) { owimage[s] = wimage; }
            var wviewport = $(window).width();
            if ((wviewport - 2 * wbutton) < owimage[s]) {
                wimage = wviewport - 2 * wbutton;
                $(this).attr("width", wimage);
            }
        }
    });
    $("video").each(function (idx) {
        var wvideo = $(this).width();
        var hvideo = $(this).height();
        if (!owvideo || wvideo > owvideo) {
            owvideo = wvideo;
            ohvideo = hvideo;
            ratio = ohvideo / owvideo;
        }
        var wviewport = $(window).width();
        if ((wviewport - 2 * wbutton) < owvideo) {
            var wvideo = wviewport - 2 * wbutton;
            $(this).width(wvideo);
            var p = $(this).parent("div");
            p.width(wvideo);
            p.height(wvideo * ratio);
            console.log($(this).width() + " " + p.width());
        }
    });
```

The function is called at resize.
The complete code is in
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/js/mobile_video.js
What's the error and how can I make it work?
Best regards - Ulrich

Comment: Which `.width()` isn't working? You have quite a few in your code.

Comment: $(this).width(wvideo); // on video it works
    var p = $(this).parent("div");
    p.width(wvideo); // on div it does not work
    p.height(wvideo * ratio); // but this works

Comment: However, in the meantime I found a different solution: Changed div to span with attribute display:inline-block. In this way the span adjusts its width and height to its content. Found this in another thread at stackoverflow.